# Как преобразовать строку в hex формат цвета?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, color, hex

Как с помощью `input()` получить `hex` код цвета?

Обычно я делал это так `white = 0xffffff`, но с преобразованием строки возникли проблемы

Мне нужно именно преобразование в `hex`, а не запись строки `ffffff` для дальнейшего преобразования в `rgb`

Код:

```
class Color:

    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.value = hex(val)

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n{} - #{}\n".format(self.name, str(self.value).replace('0x', ''))


colors = []
for i in range(1):
    n = input('Name: ')
    v = input('Value: ')
    colors.append(Color(n, v))
```

Пример ввода:

```
Name: White
Value: ffffff
```

Вывод:

```
White - #ffffff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я поменял:

```
class Color:

    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.value = int(val, 16) # преобразуем из 16-ричного числа в int

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n{} - #{}\n".format(self.name, hex(self.value).replace('0x', '')) # а тут обратно из int в 16-ричное

colors = []
for i in range(1):
    n = input('Name: ')
    v = input('Value: ')
    colors.append(Color(n, v))

print(colors[0])
```

Ввод:

```
Name: White
Value: ffffff
```

Вывод:

```
White - #ffffff
```